# How to set html link <a href> dynamically using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a menu in my web application like this

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:52451/Voronezh/Settings.aspx">Settings</a</li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:52451/LoginPages/Welcome.aspx">Log out</a</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to set these href links dynamically if some special condition is true.

I've tried the following:

HTML code

```
<li><a runat="server" id="toSettings" onserverclick="toSettings_ServerClick">Settings</a></li>
```

C# code

```
protected void toSettings_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (condition)
         toSettings.HRef = "http://localhost:52451/Voronezh/Settings.aspx"; 
       else
         {...}      
    }
```

but it doesn't work: I stay on the same page instead of moving to the Settings page.

Where is a mistake? What should be changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `HRef` won't do much here - it changes the link, it doesn't have any direct effect on the page. Try [Response.Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), I think this is what you're looking for. I.e:

```
// inside the if statement
Response.Redirect("Settings.aspx"); // note - this is the local path
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is ASP.NET C#

Redirect method from the HttpResponse should be what you are looking for.

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build your menu dynamically in code behind you should probably use a `<asp:Literal ID="menu" runat="server"/>` tag in ASPX and fill it in the `Page_Load` event like

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    menu.Text = GenerateMenu();
}

private string GenerateMenu() {
    if (yourcondition) {
        return "<div><ul><li><a href="...."></a></li></ul></div>"; 
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to doing a postback, executing the logic, and then doing a redirect would be to change the link tag to the hyperlink control, execute the logic on page load, and set the properties dynamically.

HTML:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="toSettings" Text="Settings" runat="server"/>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  toSettings.NavigateUrl = "http://localhost:52451/Voronezh/Settings.aspx";
}
```

This way you could even change the text (use `toSettings.Text = "Text to display";`) or the visibility (use `toSettings.Visible = false;`) if needed.